# Giving app uri and web url in App indexing

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-app-indexing, google-search-platform

I am working on App Indexing and follows the Google developers guide. I have no idea on that why we have to give both app uri and web url.

FYI...

[App indexing api](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/appindexingapi)

Explain about the both arguments.

Comment: what i understood from their doc is: whenever you search on google about lets say movie in your device, it will give you app list which are installed in you device enabled with app indexing. e.g. xyz app for movie in your device installed with app index. now you are searching in your device browser(google) for movie ****. If that xyz app has **** movie, your search results will display xyz app name with details in search results. So when you click on it, it will directly open xyz app with that movie details. hope you will get idea from above. feel free to ask more. :)

Comment: @Ripal Tamboli Want more. Could you explain more about the app uri and web url? Why should I give the both in an Activity?

Comment: yes.... the names suggests itself the meaning of it. In simple word, Web URL you can use to navigate from search result to your website and App URL helps you to navigate to your application from search result in case of you have website and android app respectively. IMDB is example of website and also native android app they have to search your interested movie. :) hope this will clear your doubt. let me know if more query

Comment: Sure will contact you when I want more on this... :)

Comment: Ok. Np. I will always be there. :)

Comment: @RipalTamboli This statement AppIndexingLink item1 = new AppIndexingLink(appUri1, webUrl1,this.findViewById(R.id.icon)); gives NullPointerException. As they said [Web URL is option](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/appindexingapi)tried by giving null to web URL parameter.Same Exception occured.

Comment: @RipalTamboli Kindly refer my another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139472/need-app-indexing-enabled-sample-code-part) and do some.

Comment: @RipalTamboli What are all the steps need to consider to test the AppIndexing working with Google app ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand Google tracks the number of times a webpage is visited. Higher the number of visits, higher is its rank in google search results for concerned key words.

When you use app-indexing API you link the web page with a page in your application. Let's say there is a photograph that can be viewed in your application as well as on web page. So the WEB_URI parameter would be the link your photograph on the web and the APP_URI would be the deep link that will lead to that photograph in your application.

Google will track the number of times the photograph is viewed in the application as well as on the web and results will be combined. 
Also google tracks the amount of time a user spends viewing that photograph. This helps in determinig the relevance of that photograph.